# Laravel: AJAX request endpoints in routes/api.php or routes/web.php?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a Laravel app where I fetch and update data asynchronously from my frontend. My question is: Do the endpoints for the AJAX requests go into the `routes/api.php` or in the `routes/web.php`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally in `web.php` as the routes will use the 'web' middleware to access the session and other web-related middleware (CSRF ecc..)

`api.php` is dedicated to 'stateless' API calls, where you don't want to use session but instead use stateless specific functions such as api authentication throttle and so on

Answer (score 3):

The `routes/web.php` file defines routes that are for your web interface. These routes are assigned the `web` middleware group, which provides features like `session state` and `CSRF protection`. So generally your all routes having `web` middleware goes to `routes/web.php`.

If your route having `api` middleware then it will goes to `routes/api.php`.